# Java Localdatetime parsing setting offset +5:30 whereas I want offset to be 00:00:00

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, java-time, localdatetime

I have the code as below

```
    String d = "2011-10-24";

    Fun fun = new Fun();
    fun.setTmp(LocalDateTime.parse(d + " 00:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

    fun.save(); // it's saving as 2011-10-24 05:30:00 whereas I want it to be 2011-10-24 00:00:00
```

And whenever I am saving this by setting into an entity to my db, it's adding 5:30 as offset

Comment: A localdatetime itself does not have a timezone offset. How does your code save it? It seems to get converted into an `OffsetDateTime` or something else that can hold timezone information.

Comment: hey @f1sh, i am also confused, because when I am printing fun.getTmp() it's showing as 2011-10-24 00:00:00 before save but in db when it's getting saved then in table it's showing 2011-10-24 05:30:00

I am new to java and spring, what do you think could be the issue ?

Comment: Works for me! What is setTmp doing?

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that you're living in India, and your database is showing the timestamp in your system timezone (which is, I assume, 5:30 ahead of UTC).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ZonedDateTime to alter time zones:

```
String d = "2011-10-24 00:00:00";
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(d, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toString());
```